# Convert Boolean to Validated[List[String], Unit]

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have plenty of validation methods which return a boolean. today error handling is done by doing if/else on these Booleans.

I am trying to remove this nested if/else by using Cats Validated Monad.

in each place where a boolean is being returned, I want to convert it to Validation[List[String], Unit]

I wrote this code

```
val check1 = doCheck(...).valid[List[String]].ensure{
  logStuff(...)
  List("wrong")
}(_ == true)
```

This gives me the data type of Validated[List[String], Boolean] but I want Validated[List[String], Unit]

I tried

```
val check1 = doCheck(...).invalid[Unit].ensure{
  logStuff(...)
  List("wrong")
}(_ == true)
```

Now the data type of check1 is Validated[Any, Unit]

How can I get the datatype I want without really writing explicit if/else statements.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution is to use `map`:

```scala
val check1: Validated[List[String], Unit] = 
  doCheck("...").valid.ensure {
    logStuff("...")
    List("wrong")
  }(identity).map(_ => ())
```

Another solution (my hypothesis is that `doCheck` accepts a `String` value, to be validated, in this example), could be:

```scala
val check1: Validated[List[String], Unit] =
  "...".valid.ensure {
    logStuff("...")
    List("wrong")
  }(doCheck).map(_ => ())
```

Alternatively you could use [mouse](https://github.com/benhutchison/mouse):

```scala
import mouse.all._

implicit class PimpedBoolean (b: Boolean) {
  def ensure[T](l: => T): Validated[T, Unit] =
    b.either(l, ()).toValidated
}

val check1: Validated[List[String], Unit] =
  doCheck("...").ensure {
    logStuff("...")
    List("wrong")
  }
```